# Find continuous martingale, such that it's quadratic variation is a deterministic continuous function

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Given a non decreasing continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ with $f(0)=0$.

I want to find a continuous martingale $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ , such that it's quadratic variation is equal to $f$, i.e. $\langle X,X\rangle_t=f(t)$ for all $t\ge 0$.

Let $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be standard brownian motion. I find $E[W_{f(t)}^2]=f(t)$. So I was considering to define $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ with $X_t:=W_{f(t)}$.

Which just looks too simple to me. Is this actually right?

Comment: $X_t = W_{f(t)}$ is correct. However, in order to show that $\langle X,X\rangle_t = f(t)$, it is not enough to prove that $E[X_t^2] = f(t)$. You have to check that $X_t^2 - f(t)$ is a martingale. Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485140/why-for-a-continous-local-martingale-on-an-enlarged-probability-space-it-possi?rq=1) might be of interest as it shows that any continuous martingale $X$ with quadratic variation $f$ admits the representation $X_t = W_{f(t)}$ for *some* Brownian motion $W$.

Comment: If you assume $f$ is continuously differentiable another option could be to define $X_t=\int_0^t (f'(s))^{(1/2)} dW(s)$ then its quadratic variation is $\int_0^t f'(s)ds=f(t)$.

Comment: Thanks already, for your fast answers! I will think about this more, because, as you mention: It has to be a martingale with respect to a filtration. I may post an answer on this myself afterwards.

Comment: Well, I am still struggling finding an idea why $(W_{f(t)})_{t\ge 0}$ is a martingale for some brownian motion $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$. Do you have any hints on this? Is it just possible to define this process on the Filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{f(t)})_{t\ge 0}$  where $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\ge 0}$ denotes the filtration of $W$?